# Need to create hyperlinks in AWS lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, boto3, amazon-chime

I am using AWS lambda to process a csv file and send out a message in chime to my team on a daily basis.  I need to make a part of the message a hyperlink.

Current output: ID: https://www.example.com/ID=123456

Required output: ID:  [123456](https://www.example.com/ID=123456)

and when one clicks on the ID, it should take the user to a link like "https://www.google.com/ID=123456"

I am using urllib3 to send the output from aws lambda to chime group. I believe chime only offers Markdown or code type formatting. I would like to know if it is possible to implement a solution in the aws lambda function itself.

Comment: You can code any solution in Lambda that is supported by the programming language you are using. All Lambda is after all is a function call in the cloud.

Comment: Got it!! I realised that chime offers an option to use markdown when I went through the documentation. Thank you